# Enlarge a Pixel Art image with Pixen

Tags: resize, pixel-art

Somebody can please tell me how to enlarge pixel art using Pixen? I've drawn something but i don't know the procedure to enlarge the image so that it can be seen in a normal size.

Comment: I don't know anything about Pixen but I contacted them with the link to here. Maybe someone will respond. I don't have an OS that supports it to try out myself.

Comment: There is scale controller in the Pixen, thus you should find something like "Scale the canvas" option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logic of a question you need "Scale Canvas" function.

As we can see on the screenshot there is addressing to this function on the developer page, however, the link directs to nothing related to the scaling. So, probably, this function was disabled or changed, but it should be there eventually.

[image]

Comment: Yes it is the "scale canvas" function the one that answers my question! I've tried it out and it works.